# How to change a value in an input element using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, css, selenium

I got a input element that I need to clear the actual value and input another one.

The HTML has the following structure:

```
<input class="input-mini" type="text" name="daterangepicker_start" value="">
```

I used the following code to find this element:

```
test = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text'][name='daterangepicker_start']")
```

Then I got a list of 7 elements and I guess the first one is the one. So a tried to clear the field and after send the new value as following:

```
test[0].clear()
test[0].send_keys('02/07/2019')
```

However, for both codes I got the same error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)
```

Comment: Did you try with `find_element_by_class_name`?

Comment: I tried "test= browser.find_elements_by_class_name('daterangepicker_start')" but I got a empty list

Comment: Try with `test= browser.find_elements_by_class_name('input-mini')`

Comment: @RafaelSchettini: Is the date field disabled or read-only? Is it hidden from view? This can cause the error you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Then I got a list of 20 elements.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, the find is not hidden

Comment: Which website is it? or whole html?

Comment: "Then I got a list of 7 elements and I guess the first one is the one." What was this guess based on? How do you know it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, the element can be under a `<div` that is considered ***hidden***, I have experienced this before, sometimes you can try `.click()` to make the element ***Interactable***, like this:

```
test[0].click()
test[0].clear()
test[0].send_keys('02/07/2019')
```

In case the above does not allow the element to change to an interactable state, try changing the value with javascript:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", test[0], "02/07/2019")
```

I would also recommend to look through the element list and figure out which one within the list is actually the element you're trying to interact with, in case it's not truly `test[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
test = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "input[type='text'][name='daterangepicker_start']")))
test[0].clear()
test[0].send_keys('02/07/2019')
```

Comment: Check if the element is present in the iframe.